# Membership can't validate user after providing machineKey

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, membership

I have a web site with two endpoints, let's say **www.mydomain.com** and **mydomain.com**.

I need my user stay loged in when he jumps from one domain to another.

For this task I could force my users to login on one of domain (let's call it the main) and if somebody visits another - just redirect him to the main domain.

But I have read that I can use [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx) and share the same authentication ticket accross multiple domains.

So I decided to give a try to this approach, but it doesn't work for me... the main question why?

What I did:

1. I generated new machineKey from this [service](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey).
2. Added it in my `web.config`.

After this step my old membership provider stoped working correctly. It doesn't validate users with right passwords.

I suppose it's because all passwords in my current database should be encrypted by values from [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations) section.

Could anybody point me at what I am doing wrong and is it possible to make shared authentication with machineKeys and existing membership database that contains passwords in hashed format?

I also experimented with addint `protection="All"` (I assume that it shouldn't work with hashed password because it forces its encryption by machineKeys) and `domain="mydomain.com"` attributes to my `<forms/>` section in `web.config`, but - no luck.

Comment: Are the passwords hashed or encrypted? If they are hashed, the machine keys shouldn't matter.

Comment: My membership provider doesn't has PasswordFormat attribute and I assume that they I hashed. What could be a problem if when I add machineKeys section - membership stops working?

Comment: The fact that the passwords are encrypted and not hashed. In this case the machine keys are used to encrypt them. Also could you clarify what you mean by *stop working*? Do you get some exception or it just fails to validate them?

Comment: When I add machineKey section and call Membership.ValidateUser(login, password) with right credentials - it returns 'false'. If I remove machine keys - it works nicely again.

Comment: I just checked Membership.Provider.PasswordFormat and it returns Hashed. Also in my db Membership.PasswordFormat all values set as '1'. It's hashed.

Comment: I have the same problem/symptoms as you: adding a machinekey causes existing users to fail to login. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, I didn't find solution for this problem.

Comment: I asked a similar question and got [a useful answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21733831/49942). My problem was I hadn't specified the old hash algorithm, so it was using the default algorithm; when I added a machinekey that changed/specified the default hash algorithm; so to fix this I needed to specify explicitly the old `hashAlgorithmType` in the `membership` element.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21733831/49942) defining a machinekey might change the default hash algorithm.